# How to global declare broadcast receiver

Tags: android

As seen in the image, I have 4 screens. All the 4 screens implement the broadcast receiver. Instead of repeating the code again and again I would like to implement the receiver in the first screen and scan for changes in all the screens. How can I do that?.

Also, I am declaring custom fonts for each activity. How can I declare custom font globally?.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could do any of the following, depending on the requirements:

1. create a single, global BR via the manifest that will be turned off/on according to your activities flow. make it communicate with the activities using something like LocalBroadcastReceiver.
2. create a class that has the base functionality of the BR you've created, while each of the activities will use it differently.
3. create a base activity that all activities use, which has the same functionality of BR handling.

I'm sure there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of repeating the code again and again I would like to
> implement the receiver in the first screen and scan for changes in all
> the screens

First 2 that come to my mind:

## 1

Base screen class maybe? You could dynamically register receiver in the base class and the derivatives would just receive the callback methods.

## 2

You could create single Host Activity and register the BroadcastReceiver and the screens could be fragmens attached to this activity which I would do provided that I understood your problem correctly ofc.

> I am declaring custom fonts for each activity. How can I declare
> custom font globally?.

Well, there is Apple's invention - the True Type Font (TTF) - there are plenty of websites filled with different types of those.

Here is a Mark Murphy's example concerning setting fonts - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Fonts/FontSampler/src/com/commonsware/android/fonts/FontSampler.java

If you use Support Library then as @android-developer suggested it is reasonable to use Local BroadcastReceiver as it does not send the broadcast to every app and works only within your process.